# How do I resolve conflicting session cookies on specific subdomain?

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii

For starters, we're using the Yii framework to create our sites and it is handling the creation of the cookies.

We have a site with many subdomains so the main site has a session cookieParams of ".sitename.com".

Something like this:

- www.sitename.com
- a.sitename.com
- b.sitename.com
- admin.sitename.com

We have `www`, `a`, and `b` to share the same session cookie and this works great.

However, we have one special admin subdomain that has a different user system and login mechanism, so we have a separate session cookieParam of "admin.sitename.com".

The problem is, if someone gets a session cookie from the main site, logging into the admin site fails, because the main site's ".sitename.com" cookie appears to be taking precedence. Deleting the cookie for the main site fixes the issue temporarily until the browser visits the main site again.

Is there any way around this, or is there a better way to set the cookies domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just have the admin site use a different cookie name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After ispecting how `yii` accomplishes this with their `gii` tool I set the following in my `config.php` and got it working.

```
<?php 

$config = array(
    ...
    'components'=>array(
        ...
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'class' => 'WebUser',
            // Create a custom key prefix for the user cookie
            'stateKeyPrefix'=>'customkey',
        ),
        ...
        'session' => array (
            // Provide a custom name for the session id to differentiate it 
            // from the default PHPSESSID
            // Cannot use dots in the session id :(
            'sessionName' => 'custom_session_id',
            // Keep session stored in db for use accross load balancer
            'class' => 'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
            'connectionID' => 'db',
        ),
        ...
    ),
);
```

Comment: session id name helped for me too. PHPSESID with a domain.com and another cookie with .domain.com both allowed. and both caused total collapse in yii which was not diagnosed in any other way. until, i changed cookie name itself. Finally! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use different session names. In plain php you call session_name() before session_start(). I'm not very familiar with Yii framework, but the class CHttpSession seems to be a thin wrapper around the php functions and it has a setSessionName() method.